# Switch Fragments inside a Tab

Tags: android, android-fragments

How do I switch fragments inside a tab?

My application contains three fragments, AFragment, BFragment, and CFragment. These fragments, in turn, correspond to their own layout files: AFragment contains a Button, and BFragment and CFragment have TextView. There is a fourth layout file named activity_main.

Now, I have four classes, MainActivity, AFragment, BFragment and CFragment. The classes AFragment, BFragment, CFragment only the typical contain OnCreateView on each of them.

MainActivity contains this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    appContext = getApplicationContext();

    //ActionBar
     ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
     actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

     ActionBar.Tab PlayerTab = actionbar.newTab().setText("Fragment A");
     ActionBar.Tab StationsTab = actionbar.newTab().setText("Fragment B");

     Fragment PlayerFragment = new AFragment();
     Fragment StationsFragment = new BFragment();

     PlayerTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(PlayerFragment));
     StationsTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(StationsFragment));

     actionbar.addTab(PlayerTab);
     actionbar.addTab(StationsTab);
```

And then the TabListener:

```
class MyTabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
public Fragment fragment;

public MyTabsListener(Fragment fragment) {
    this.fragment = fragment;
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.appContext, "Reselected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    ft.remove(fragment);
}
```

}

As you can see, activity_main.xml only contains a LinearLayout with an id 'fragment_container' for tabs AFragment and BFragment. Now I want it in such a way that clicking a button in AFragment switches the entire AFragment to CFragment. How can I achieve this? Thank you.

(EDIT) I did the following but my app crashed on start. What did I do wrong?

I added the following on my MainActivity.java, just below the ActionBar sequence:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
appContext = getApplicationContext();

//ActionBar
....
....
....
Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            CFragment fragment = new CFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Not related but respect java coding conventions. Variables start with a lower case letter. Your code's gonna be easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

- get a fragment transaction using the (support) fragment manager of your activity.
- replace AFragment by CFragment as you did in onTabSelected
- commit your transaction.

Also, please note :

- don't keep references on your fragment, you actually prevent garbage collection from occuring. You should create your fragments once, not every time. In TabSelected, check if the fragment is known by the fragment manager (using findFragmentByTag). If not, create it. If it is, just re-replace it.
- share your listener, you don't need one by tab.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, sir. Do you have an example how to do the fragment transaction on OnClick? And where shall I put it - inside afragment, or in the MainActivity? Sorry if my questions sound so dumb.

Comment: You should do it inside your activity as it will know both fragments. It's not dumb, there are actually some details that will not be straightforward, but google and SOF are your friends.

Comment: Hello, Snicolas. I added something on my code... can you take a look at it? I updated my question. :(